# Index already exist exception upon create index on postgresql

Tags: java, database, postgresql, indexing, b-tree

I am using PostgreSQL database. I am creating 10 tables for different companies.In order to access records faster, I am attempting to create indexes on each table. However, PostgreSQL throws an exception for indexes that are created for all companies after the first. Is it not possible to create the same index on different tables within the same database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres index names must be unique within the same schema. If you omit the name then Postgres will create a unique name for you.

Comment: Thnx a l aot.. got it. Exactly what you mentioned .

Comment: IMHO, user5891223, shouldn't it be up voted if you accepted this answer?